# JSF 2.2 : a @NoneScoped bean, injected into another broader scoped Managed Bean is NULL in the @PostConstruct

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, dependency-injection

I believe this question may have been answered in some other threads, but so far I still cannot manage to make it work with my configuration.

As far as I understand, a **@NoneScoped** bean, injected into another one, will live as long as the scope of the Acceptor Bean.

And so far, it it true... except that it seems the Bean is not yet available during the **@PostConstruct** method of the Acceptor Bean.

For example, let's say we have an base abstract bean **BaseScopedBean** with the following ManagedProperty injection:

```
public abstract class BaseScopedBean implements IBaseBean {

  @ManagedProperty(value = "#{resourceBundleProvider}")
  private ResourceBundleProvider resourceBundleProvider;

  public void setResourceBundleProvider(ResourceBundleProvider resourceBundleProvider) {
    this.resourceBundleProvider = resourceBundleProvider;
  }

  public ResourceBundleProvider getResourceBundleProvider() {
    return this.resourceBundleProvider;
  }
}
```

where **ResourceBundleProvider** looks just like this:

```
@ManagedBean ( name = "resourceBundleProvider")
@NoneScoped
public class ResourceBundleProvider {

  public ResourceBundle getBundle(String bundleName) {
      FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
      return context.getApplication().getResourceBundle(context, bundleName);
  }

  public String getValue(String bundleName, String key) {

      try {
          return getBundle(bundleName).getString(key);
      } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
          return '!' + key + '!';
      }
  }

  public String getValue(String bundleName, String key, Object... params) {

      try {
          return MessageFormat.format(getBundle(bundleName).getString(key), params);
      } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
          return '!' + key + '!';
      }
  }
}
```

And then, we define an **@ApplicationScoped** bean that extends **BaseScopedBean**, and tries to access the *resourceBundleProvider* during a **@PostConstruct** operation

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class MenuBean extends BaseScopedBean {

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
      System.out.println(getResourceBundleProvider());
  }
}
```

The System.out.println(resourceBundleProvider)  in the **@PostConstruct** prints **NULL**

However, accessing the *resourceBundleProvide*r later on, in a method invoked from a Facelet EL expression, returns a valid created instance, for example.

The question:  **Is this the expected behaviour ?**   I believe the *resourceBundleProvider* managed property should be already available in the **@PostConstruct**.

I'm using **WildFly 8.2.0.Final** with **Apache Myfaces 2.2.7** , not the original Mojarra implementation.

Any ideas ?

Thanks a lot in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that , so far, with Apache MyFaces 2.2.7 ( and presumably 2.2.8 ) this seems to be a bug... that was previously fixed in 2.1.x versions !!

With Mojarra ( at least 2.2.12 ), the behavior is the expected one.

Comment: It turns out that at the end, the problem relied more on JBoss WildFly 8.x server than on MyFaces ... !! 8.x has a bug on the following class: https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/8.x/jsf/injection/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/jsf/injection/MyFacesLifecycleProvider.java
which has been corrected in WildFly 9.x and above:
https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/9.x/jsf/injection/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/jsf/injection/MyFacesLifecycleProvider.java